# What items make a good class for Terraria? (All classes: Melee, Mage, Ranged, Summoner)

Tags: terraria, terraria-mobile

Please list all items that would make this class A beast. I was wondering what to use since I have all items.

Comment: This is an opinion based question.

Answer (score 4):

There is no "best item" setup for a class (in my opinion). Classes are flexible, and you can use a wide variety of items. If you want something to work off of, this guide can help you immensely https://terraria.fandom.com/wiki/Guide:Class_setups. The Terraria wiki is generally useful, so you should use it when you forget something or need some quick info.